# cocoa: Drag and Drop svg images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, file-type, nspasteboard

I'm working on the simple app that displays icons in the NSCollectionView. NSCollectionView displays icons preview in png format and users can drag it to the image editor. I would like to allow user drag & drop not only png, but also svg files.  I loaded svg image data but how can I copy it to NSPasteboard to drug svg data to Sketch app for example.

Comment: I don't know the details, but I can tell you that most applications will not handle SVG, but many can import vector PDF. Also, Sketch has trouble taking any vector data from drag & drop.

Answer (score 0):

Applications like Sketch do not drag and drop SVG data. Instead they are creating a temporary svg file and put the file URL into the `NSDraggingItem`. This allows some kind of SVG support.